# Does gensim.model.TfidfModel have the term frequency saved?

Tags: python, nlp, counter, gensim, tf-idf

**Does `gensim.model.TfidfModel` have the term frequency saved?**

From the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html), they use the formula:

```
weights_i_j = frequency_i_j * log_2(D / doc_freq_i)
```

And when I prob the attributes of the `dir(model)` (TfidfModel object) with the following code:

```
>>> import gensim.downloader as api
>>> from gensim.models import TfidfModel
>>> from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
>>>
>>> dataset = api.load("text8")
>>> dct = Dictionary(dataset)  # fit dictionary
>>> corpus = [dct.doc2bow(line) for line in dataset]  # convert dataset to BoW format
>>>
>>> model = TfidfModel(corpus)  # fit model
>>> dir(model)
```

I'm getting:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_adapt_by_suffix',
 '_apply',
 '_load_specials',
 '_save_specials',
 '_smart_save',
 'dfs',
 'id2word',
 'idfs',
 'initialize',
 'load',
 'normalize',
 'num_docs',
 'num_nnz',
 'save',
 'wglobal',
 'wlocal']
```

But I can't seem to find where are the term frequencies stored.

**If the term frequencies are not saved, is there a reason why?** Since it's already stored to compute the weights anyways.

**Is there a way to retrieve the term frequencies somehow during the fitting process?**

Answer (score 1):

Term frequency represents how frequently a term occurs in a document.

The BOW corpus converts each term in a in each document into (tokenId, frequency).

For example,

```py
import gensim.corpora import Dictionary
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

text_data = ['dog cat horse donkey', 'dog woof cat meow', 'horse horse horse', 'lion tiger wolf']

# Tokenise each string   
tokeniser = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

# Create list of tokens
docs = list(map(tokeniser.tokenize, text_data))

# Create Dictionary mapping tokens to their ids
dct = Dictionary(docs) 

# Create BOW corpus: (tokenId, frequency) for each token in each doc
corpus = [dct.doc2bow(line) for line in docs]
```

Now examine your BOW Corpus to see Term Frequencies

```
# BOW Corpus
 In [56]: corpus
 Out[56]:
 [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)],
 [(0, 1), (1, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)],
 [(3, 3)],
 [(6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]]
```

Examine Dictionary to see tokenId to term mapping

```
# Dictionary
In [60]: dct.token2id
Out[60]:
{u'cat': 0,
 u'dog': 1,
 u'donkey': 2,
 u'horse': 3,
 u'lion': 6,
 u'meow': 4,
 u'tiger': 7,
 u'wolf': 8,
 u'woof': 5}
```